# In Powershell, how do I split text from Compare-Object input and sort by one of the split values?

Tags: powershell, split, compareobject

Here is a sample input from two different files `hash1.txt` and `hash2.txt`:

hash1.txt:

```
abcdef01234567890 \path\to\file1.txt
01234567890abcdef \path\to\file2.txt
a0b1c2d3e4f567890 \path\to\file3.txt
```

hash2.txt

```
abcdef01234567890 \path\to\file1.txt
11234567890abcdef \path\to\file2.txt
q0b1c2d3e4f567890 \path\to\file3.txt
```

I can do a simple compare with:

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-Content "$hash1" | Select -Skip $numskip1) -DifferenceObject (Get-Content "$hash2" | Select -Skip $numskip2 )
```

The default `Compare-Object` output is fine, but would like to sort it by matching file paths separated by a blank line.

So in this case file2.txt and file3.txt have a different hash value with matching file paths. But how do I go about providing output like this:

```
01234567890abcdef \path\to\file2.txt    <=
11234567890abcdef \path\to\file2.txt    =>

a0b1c2d3e4f567890 \path\to\file3.txt    <=
q0b1c2d3e4f567890 \path\to\file3.txt    =>
```

Sorry, I'm not a programmer, I'm just trying to figure out how to make it easier to sort through a pile of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Group-Object) to group your results by file path and then use [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/ForEach-Object) to format the members of each group separately with [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Format-Table):

```bash
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-Content "$hash1" | Select -Skip $numskip1) -DifferenceObject (Get-Content "$hash2" | Select -Skip $numskip2 ) |
  Group-Object { $_.InputObject -replace '^.+? ' } | 
  ForEach-Object { 
    $_.Group | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | 
      Out-String | ForEach-Object TrimEnd
  }
```

Note that the output of this command is suitable *for display only*, due to use of a `Format-*` cmdlet.

The purpose of the [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) acting as a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties) passed to `Group-Object` is to group only by the file-path portion of the line:

- `-replace '^.+ '` uses the [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator to remove one or more (`+`) characters (`.`) non-greedily (`?`) from the start (`^`) of each string, up to and including the (first)   (space), so that the strings are compared by the file paths contained in them only; e.g.,
  `'abcdef01234567890 \path\to\file1.txt' -replace '^.+? '` yields
  `\path\to\file1.txt`
- For a detailed explanation of the regex and the ability to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/qEG7LP/1).

The purpose of the `Out-String | ForEach-Object TrimEnd` part - courtesy of [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) - is to reduce the number of empty lines between groups to 1.
You'll still get an empty *initial* line, however.
To eliminate it too, append `| Out-String | ForEach-Object Trim` to the entire pipeline.